# should I use shouldComponentupdate?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Recently, i realized child component always re-render when parent change even props and state of child component didn't change. It's make my project is so slow.
So, i used `shouldComponentupdate` to fixed that.
But, should i really use it?

If i should use it. Is there any way to apply it to `React-hook`?

This is code in my `shouldComponentupdate`

```
shouldComponentupdate(nextProps, nextState){
if(JSON.stringify(nextProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props) ||
JSON.stringify(nextState) !== JSON.stringify(this.state)
){
 return true
}
return false
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you're just comparing the current props/state to the previous props/state, you should be able to remove `shouldComponentUpdate` and use [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). The only difference is that PureComponent does a shallow props/state check, whereas you're using JSON.stringify to do a deep value equality check, so you should make sure a shallow check is still doing the optimization.

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent { // No need for shouldComponentUpdate
```

The equivalent feature for functional components (including ones that use hooks) is [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  ...
}

export default React.memo(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-render of parental component will always trigger re-render of all its children components. So implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` in child component will not help.

One solution you can work on is delegate current props/state of parent component to lower ones, i.e. listen to props and render UI at children components and let parent component keep track of less items.